# CSS: Chrome and Safari seem to 'add' border to width, while IE, Firefox & Opera don't

Tags: safari, google-chrome, border, padding, margin

I'm trying to achieve cross-browser consistency for my website.

It's about this page: http://www[insert-dot-here]geld[insert-dash-here]surfen[insert-dot-here]nl/uitbetalingen.html (please note that I prefer this URL not to be made crawlable for seo-bots)

If you view this page in IE, Firefox or Opera, everything is fine, but in Chrome and Safari the tables are a little out of line (as you'll probably clearly notice).

What seems to be the problem?

It appears to me that in Chrome and Safari the left and right border (2px) in total are added to the set table width, while in the other browsers the border is considered part of the width.

The (most) relevant CSS-lines are the following ones (from the `table.css` file, also available through the page's source file):

> ```
> table.uitbetaling {
>  margin: 11px 18px 10px 19px;
>  border: 1px solid #8ccaee;
>  width: 498px;
>  padding: 0;
> }
> table.uitbetaling img, table.uitbetaling td {
>  margin: 0;
>  border: 0;
>  padding: 0;
>  width: 496px;
> }
> table.uitbetaling tr {
>  margin: 0;
>  border: 0;
>  padding: 0 1px 0 0;
> }
> ```

So basically I have used a table-structure to organize images, like this: (the class of the table is `uitbetaling`)

> ```
> <table>
> <tr><td><img /></td></tr>
> <tr><td><img /></td></tr>
> ...
> <tr><td><img /></td></tr>
> </table>
> ```

If, here, I set the width of `table.uitbetaling` and `table.uitbetaling img, table.uitbetaling td` to the same value (e.g. both `496` or `498`), the "problem" in Chrome and Safari is solved, however in Firefox the right side border is than blank. Because the right-side border can't "fit" in anymore. `img` and `td` must be at least 2px more narrow than `table.uitbetaling` for the right-border be visible in Firefox.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Btw; is that website legal, according to Dutch laws?

Comment: "please note that I prefer this URL not to be made crawlable for seo-bots"    

Too late. You're number 1 and that page is number 2 on Google. That's what they make htaccess for.

Comment: Regarding crawlability: ll major bots respect `robots.txt`. Simply tell them to leave: http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays you should be using the HTML5 doctype, if you're having issues about borders adding themselves to the element's width look up the CSS style: **box-sizing**

**border-box** - include border width/height and padding width/height or basically the width you set includes the borders/padding

**content-box** - the width you set on the element is only the content area, this does not include padding or borders

There is also padding-box which I don't use, usually the above two are enough.

Now sometimes, I think IE8 uses a different box-sizing than Chrome/FF etc, this is why sometimes you have issues. You can always debug and check what the box-sizing is set to.

*Note: if you don't have the DOCTYPE then you're in quirks mode, and IE differs WILDLY from Chrome/FF on the box-sizing/box model - and that's your problem right there*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
```

Answer (score 0):

segment your code into its simplest elements and test them on each browser. When you find the differences you can use different methods of browser detection to subtly alter the code for each instance. With that said... if you do not want to go stark raving mad, and CSS will do that more then anything in programming let the pixel go if you can.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, I usually open a table in this way:

`<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`

It is "old" HTML, but at least it forces coherency along browsers, and then I apply CSS as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd checked with Opera 11, Google Chrome 7.0.517.44 and FireFox 3.6.12 have seen no difference with your site design.

Comment: He probably fixed it before 7 months!

Comment: /me smiles. I think not only he.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the DTD (DOCTYPE)?

Read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250395.aspx

It looks that browsers have different ways to display the borders, but the DOCTYPE declaration (which goes at the top of the html document) force them to comply with the actual standards, at least in regard of css box model.

Note: I always use the xhtml transitional DTD to make my document as much compatible as possible...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Its good practice to always set `table{border-collapse:collapse;}` in the css, and then use `cell-padding="0"` and `cell-spacing="0"` in the html anyway.